# Convexity of $ {\bf x} \mapsto ({\bf x} - {\bf a})^\top \left( \sum_i x_i {\bf A}_i \right)^{-1}({\bf x} - {\bf a}) $

Tags: convex-analysis

Given the positive vector ${\bf a} \in {\Bbb R}_{>0}^n$ and symmetric positive definite $n \times n$ matrices ${\bf A}_1, {\bf A}_2, \dots, {\bf A}_n$, define the scalar field $f : {\Bbb R}^n \to {\Bbb R}$ by

$$ f({\bf x}) := ({\bf x} - {\bf a})^\top \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i {\bf A}_i \right)^{-1}({\bf x} - {\bf a}) $$

$x_i \geq a_i$ for all $i$. Is $f$ convex?

Without the $x_i$ in the inner parenthesis the answer is yes. I have tried to look at the shape of $f$ numerically and it does look convex for the parameters I have tried.

Comment: I suspect you do **not** know what a quadratic form is.  A quadratic form is merely a quadratic polynomial in which every monomial is degree-2.  Something like vector-transpose-times-matrix-times-vector is not necessarily a quadratic form

Comment: Yes thanks for clarifying the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing a new variable, $y \in {\Bbb R}$, the [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of $f$ is defined by

$$ ({\bf x} - {\bf a})^\top \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i {\bf A}_i \right)^{-1}({\bf x} - {\bf a}) \leq y $$

which, via the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), can be rewritten as the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI).

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i {\bf A}_i & ({\bf x} - {\bf a}) \\ ({\bf x} - {\bf a})^\top & y\end{bmatrix} \succeq {\bf O}_{n+1} $$

Hence, the epigraph of $f$ is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) and, thus, convex. Therefore, $f$ is also **convex**.

---

**Related**

- [A function is convex if and only if its epigraph is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/925835/339790)
- [How do I implement this convex quadratic-linear function in CVX?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086093/339790)
- [How is this a linear matrix inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2802826/339790)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain how we can rewrite the epigraph inequality into the linear matrix inequality? I've looked at the wikipedia article for the Schur complement but I still don't see how that step works.

Comment: @user_lambda Try to understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675492/339790) first. Do you understand every step?  This is basically Gaussian elimination for block matrices.

Comment: Yes I understand every step in that response.

Comment: @user_lambda Then you can apply it to this answer.  Start from the bottom and try to compute the Schur complement of the northwestern block

Comment: I see. So the Schur complement of the northwestern block is
$$ y-({\bf x} - {\bf a})^\top \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i {\bf A}_i \right)^{-1}({\bf x} - {\bf a}).$$ Then we know that the bottom matrix is PSD iif the Schur complement is PSD. But since the Schur complement is a scalar we have a normal inequality. Very clever! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user_lambda You are welcome. That is correct. You may want to take a look at Jean Gallier's [notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf). The relevant result is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2802848/339790) one

Answer (score -1):

Let $B \equiv \sum_i x_i A_i$. Since $A_i$ are each symmetric and positive definite and $x_i > 0$, then $B$ is also symmetric and positive definite.
$$
B[j,k] = \sum_i x_i A_i[j,k] = \sum_i x_i A_i[k,j] = B[k,j] \\
y^T B y = \sum_i x_i y^T A_i y > 0
$$

Consider some $y,z$ such that $By=z$. Then we can show that $B^{-1}$ is also symmetric and positive definite.
$$
B^{-1} = B^{-1} I = B^{-1} I^T = B^{-1} (B^{-1} B)^T = B^{-1} B^T (B^{-1})^T = B^{-1} B (B^{-1})^T = (B^{-1})^T\\
z^T B^{-1}z = z^Ty = (By)^T y = y^T B y > 0
$$

Now define $z \equiv x - a$. Then,
$$f(x) = g(z) = z^T B^{-1} z$$

So $g$ is convex in $z$. Since $f$ has the same value, but whose input is shifted by a constant $a$, $f$ is also convex in $x$.

Comment: This is not correct. You are suppressing that $A$ (or, equivalently $B$) also depends on $x$ (or, equivalently, $z$).